# 2020 Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we are holding a Q&A thread for the candidates. Questions collected [from an earlier thread](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4393/49) have been compiled into this one, which shall now serve as the space for the candidates to provide their answers.

Due to the submission count, we have selected all provided questions as well as one of our back up questions for a total of 10 questions.

As a candidate, your job is simple - post an answer to this question, citing each of the questions and then post your answer to each question given in that same answer. For your convenience, I will include all of the questions in quote format with a break in between each, suitable for you to insert your answers. Just [copy the whole thing after the first set of three dashes](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/58d218a5-aebc-4c15-bfab-3872d83a1783/view-source). Please consider putting your name at the top of your post so that readers will know who you are before they finish reading everything you have written, and also including a link to your answer on your nomination post.

Once all the answers have been compiled, this will serve as a transcript for voters to view the thoughts of their candidates, and will be appropriately linked in the Election page.

Good luck to all of the candidates!

### Oh, and when you've completed your answer, please provide a link to it after this blurb here, before that set of three dashes. Please leave the list of links in the order of submission.

To save scrolling here are links to the submissions from each candidate (in order of submission):

- [Wondercricket's answers](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4404/20275)
- [Aki Tanaka's answers](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4405/2516)

---

> 1. In your opinion, what do moderators do?
> 2. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
> 3. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?
> 4. What should responsible moderators not do with their power? What behavior have you disliked in moderators (on any SE or elsewhere) that you vow you'll never do?
> 5. A user has posted a question which by itself is fine and is answerable, however the user's actions involving the question has been troubling (ie. spamming non-answers, spamming the question link in comments across the site, defacing edits, harassing/abusive behavior to other users who answer/comment/discuss). Along with any possible sanctions against the user, do you think any action should be taken against the question?
> 6. A question was asked [a while back](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4314/48808) about lowering the close vote threshold from 5 to 3. Since moderator support for such a move is critical, do you think the current threshold is fine or should it be lowered, and why?
> 7. You (a moderator) and another community member both answer a question on the site. The other answer is well written but (objectively) incorrect, and has gathered a similar amount of upvotes to yours. What do you do?
> 8. Where do you want to see the site and/or community go in the near future? Where don't you want to see it go? (Optional: provide the rationale behind your decisions.)
> 9. The community as a whole has many things that are can be seen as lack, underdeveloped, or could use further development, compared to other sites or communities (such as our sister sites within the some category). What do you see as the top three immediate things that you would like to tackle as moderator that you cannot do as a user? Why do you think these points are important and should be prioritized?
> 10. How much do you know about the following series: *Naruto*, *One Piece,* *My Hero Academia*, and *Attack on Titan*? These series are some of the [top tags as of 2020](https://data.stackexchange.com/anime/query/1310219/2020-anime-manga-top-questions) that are seen more of than others. To date, there are still many (mostly poorly written) questions regarding the *Naruto* series despite it officially coming to an end in 2017. My Hero Academia and Attack on Titan appear to be getting more popular as the days go by. Knowing about these series is by no means a requirement, of course. But if candidates A and B are identical except that A has an encyclopedic knowledge of Naruto while B has an encyclopedic knowledge of (say) Doraemon, it may make a difference for voters.

Comment: Can I say out loud that we only have essentially one candidate now, since the other one announced that they'd sooner withdraw than participate?  What happens next?

Comment: @Makoto There's a third candidate now, so I think we're good. :)

Answer (score 10):

> 1. In your opinion, what do moderators do?

Moderators are more than just users – they are leaders. Being elected as a moderator means the community has put their trust in you to lead by example while maintaining a positive and friendly experience to all users in the community.

> 2. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?

A user who posts high quality questions and answers are not automatically exempted from following the rules.

The first thing I would do to resolve this is handle any flags accordingly, and then talk to the user about their behavior in the site. If the user complies and I see a noticeable change, then no further action would be required.

If the user continues to raise issues, then I give would them a warning and reach out to another moderator to talk to the user about their behavior. Who knows, I may have rubbed them the wrong way in the past and they do not want to listen to me specifically.

After given a warning by myself and a secondary moderator, and there are no changes in their behavior, then I would discuss with moderator team about initiating a suspension.

> 3. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

If felt like the question shouldn’t have been closed or deleted, then I would reach out to the moderator who handled the question and inquire about the reason that lead to their conclusion. Single-handedly undoing their action would be an abuse of power.

If resolution is met and both parties agreed on re-opening or un-deleting the question, then I would let them handle it as such.

> 4. What should responsible moderators not do with their power? What behavior have you disliked in moderators (on any SE or elsewhere) that you vow you'll never do?

This one ties back to #3. In my experience as a general user in other another site, I have seen a moderator close a question because they believed to be off-topic. The question was reaching into some gray areas and the on-topicness was questionable to begin with, but the community disagreed with the vote and the question received enough votes to have it re-opened. In-turn, the moderator closed the question again.

In this situation, closing the question a second time was an abuse of power and overruling the decisions of the community. Unless it is explicitly off-topic (anime/manga identification requests, recommendations, a question that isn’t even a question, etc…), I would leave it up to community to submit their close votes and flags before stepping in.

> 5. A user has posted a question which by itself is fine and is answerable, however the user's actions involving the question has been troubling (ie. spamming non-answers, spamming the question link in comments across the site, defacing edits, harassing/abusive behavior to other users who answer/comment/discuss). Along with any possible sanctions against the user, do you think any action should be taken against the question?

I say this would depend on the quality and value of the question. If it were a simple question – music identification request tagged to a specific anime for example – I would move forward with deleting the question. While these questions are answerable, they are not highly sought after and likely will go unnoticed.

Now say the question was something that would receive a lot of attention, such as [Where is Eren's father Dr. Jaeger?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/19724), then I would say leave the question open and allow people to answer. Since the user had that much negative activity, they were likely either suspended or were deleted all together (which I have seen to be the case for new or unregistered users). The question may go unaccepted, but it would be a highly valued question that people would want answered.

> 6. A question was asked [a while back](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4314/48808) about lowering the close vote threshold from 5 to 3. Since moderator support for such a move is critical, do you think the current threshold is fine or should it be lowered, and why?

I am in full support on moving forward with lowering the close vote threshold to 3 for Anime & Manga. In the last few months, I have seen many reviews struggle to past 3 votes and the last vote has typically been a moderator.

In the past there has been, and possibly can be again, a steady amount of users who go through the review queue where 5 votes would be easily achievable, but I do not believe that holds true for the time being. While being a moderator means I can finalize the close, that doesn’t mean the community should rely on moderators for such action.

> 7. You (a moderator) and another community member both answer a question on the site. The other answer is well written but (objectively) incorrect, and has gathered a similar amount of upvotes to yours. What do you do?

It is not up to a moderator to throw down the hammer and delete answers that provide incorrect information. I would simply comment on the answer to provide information on why it is incorrect, and then go on my merry way. From there, it is up to the user to decide on whether they should edit the answer to become valid and useful, or delete it entirely.

> 8. Where do you want to see the site and/or community go in the near future? Where don't you want to see it go? (Optional: provide the rationale behind your decisions.)

A majority of this section can be seen in my answers for #9. I want Anime & Manga to be a welcoming site that gives provides users with a great experience when inquiring about anime and manga. However, I feel like the scatter and confusing policies can make the site feel unwelcoming to new users and not give them much incentive to return.

> 9. The community as a whole has many things that are can be seen as lack, underdeveloped, or could use further development, compared to other sites or communities (such as our sister sites within the some category). What do you see as the top three immediate things that you would like to tackle as moderator that you cannot do as a user? Why do you think these points are important and should be prioritized?

1. Ever since I joined this community, I have seen a lack of community events. I remember there were a few watch parties in my early days, but those have since fade away. I am interested to starting these back up. Community events can provide users another kind of experience that is more than just your typically Q&A.
2. Back in July, the [A&M Monthly Engagement Post #3](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4381) was initiated to help move the site forward in implementing upcoming features and changes. Among the three topics, I would focus on organization and cleanup of tags and policies. As mentioned, there are policies that are now deprecated, and these need to be consolidated where needed and have them up-to-date.

   For example, let’s look at identification requests. In the help guide, it states questions asking to identify an anime or manga are off-topic regardless of how much information is provided. However, unless you read the meta-posted that is linked to it, you wouldn’t know that anime/manga identification requests based on cosplays or merchandise are accepted. Even though it does say you can ask about merchandise, it’s ambiguous on whether it’s acceptable criteria for identification requests (and cosplay isn’t even mentioned here).
3. In addition to #2, I would work with the moderator team and community to move forward with making music identification requests off-topic (which has been mentioned in the Anime & Manga engagement questions for both July and May). I have answered a few of these in the past, but I find them tedious and sometimes difficult to answer; especially if the track was unofficially released.

   A majority of the time, the OP (original poster) will lack the required information to allow the community effectively answer the question. The question will become unanswered for an indefinite amount of the time because the OP has left the community and leaving the question untouched.

   Another thing I would like to mention regarding these questions is that, when provide,
   timestamps could be different based on the streaming service they view it on (which I have seen a few times). When this occurs, it could effectively change the track that is being asked about and the community may provide potentially incorrect information – and we wouldn’t know until the OP says otherwise

> 10. How much do you know about the following series: *Naruto*, *One Piece,* *My Hero Academia*, and *Attack on Titan*? These series are some of the [top tags as of 2020](https://data.stackexchange.com/anime/query/1310219/2020-anime-manga-top-questions) that are seen more of than others. To date, there are still many (mostly poorly written) questions regarding the *Naruto* series despite it officially coming to an end in 2017. My Hero Academia and Attack on Titan appear to be getting more popular as the days go by. Knowing about these series is by no means a requirement, of course. But if candidates A and B are identical except that A has an encyclopedic knowledge of Naruto while B has an encyclopedic knowledge of (say) Doraemon, it may make a difference for voters.

I am seasoned in the realm of Naruto. A majority of my answers are on questions asking about this series as well as it’s squeal Boruto. While most of my knowledge comes from watching the Anime, I will provide manga references to better support my answers whenever possible. The same is also true for Attack on Titan

I have very little knowledge when it comes to both One Piece and My Hero Academia, however My Hero Academia is next on my to-watch list :)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer the questionnaire. I noticed you didn't actually nominate yet — deliberate (still working on the actual nomination thread), or accidental? :P Just trying to make the actual system mechanics were clear :)

Comment: @JNat I’m still working on the nomination thread :)

Comment: I hope you get into One Piece as well. Naruto and One Piece are my two biggest go-to topics and they definitely need a lot of clean-up. Unfortunately, I'm unable to do that myself, hence I would like to pass the mantle. Good luck :)

Comment: @SudoRahul Thanks! Agreed, the questions need some clean up. Naruto was the first anime I had ever watched, so it has a special place in my heart. I do plan on (eventually) watching One Piece, just need to sit down and barrel through it :)

Answer (score 6):

#### [Aki Tanaka](https://anime.stackexchange.com/election#post-60909)'s answers to the questionnaires

<sup>For additional context, [here are my answers to the previous 2019 Android.SE election](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2525/44325).</sup>

> 1. In your opinion, what do moderators do?

Borrowing the terms since then, moderators are "super janitors" and "exception handlers"; "super janitors" because they are basically unrestricted in cleaning up the sites, and "exception handlers" for issues that regular users cannot handle by themselves.

While in general moderators should be the "exception handlers" and let the community moderating the site, Anime.SE doesn't have enough high-rep regulars to moderate efficiently. This is where moderators can support them by being the "janitors".

> 2. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?

In general, I will be quite direct in following and enforcing the [Code of Conduct](https://anime.stackexchange.com/conduct): warning, account suspension, and account expulsion.

However, Anime.SE is lacking experts. Making them left the site because of arguments/flags is the very last action I want to take. With help of other moderators, I'll try best to make a compromise and persuade them to improve their behavior while still reducing/preventing the friction within the community.

> 3. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

Discuss with them casually but politely, just like how I will do even as a regular user. Our moderators are very rational and open-minded, and I believe we can give feedback to each other constructively without being intimidated. If it is just a single instance of disagreement, then I can live with it ;)

However, if it becomes a pattern, I will request the moderator to discuss the cause of the issue ("focus on the content, not the user") on the meta with the community, just like how regular users can and should do.

> 4. What should responsible moderators not do with their power? What behavior have you disliked in moderators (on any SE or elsewhere) that you vow you'll never do?

The obvious one is not abusing their mods' powers, including their binding votes and potentially biased/unreasonable deletion (which might be considered as "censoring") since *mods don't really own the site*.

Though, I can't remember a specific case for any behavior that I dislike for now...

> 5. A user has posted a question which by itself is fine and is answerable, however the user's actions involving the question has been troubling (ie. spamming non-answers, spamming the question link in comments across the site, defacing edits, harassing/abusive behavior to other users who answer/comment/discuss). Along with any possible sanctions against the user, do you think any action should be taken against the question?

SE has a motto to "focus on the content, not the user", which means to moderate each post as isolated as possible without bias from the poster. Depending on the quality/issue of the questions, they should be generally left open to be moderated by the community instead.

Unless, if the question is also a part of the problem (e.g. edit war), it probably needs to be locked, or in the worst case, deleted.

> 6. A question was asked [a while back](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4314/48808) about lowering the close vote threshold from 5 to 3. Since moderator support for such a move is critical, do you think the current threshold is fine or should it be lowered, and why?

It should still be lowered. With one of the candidates being elected, it also means that the site "loses" a regular vote (since mod's votes are binding). I always prefer the community to self-moderate as much as possible rather than relying on moderators.

> 7. You (a moderator) and another community member both answer a question on the site. The other answer is well written but (objectively) incorrect, and has gathered a similar amount of upvotes to yours. What do you do?

I'll put my moderator's hat off here and just act as a regular user since this doesn't need any moderator's interventions.

Generally, I'll comment to point out some of the obvious mistakes, and also possibly downvote if it really warrants. Still, I'll disengage if the comment thread may become a long debate since I've already put my answer.

While seeing highly-upvoted wrong answers may be annoying, they are technically an attempt to answer and they aren't really eligible for deletion due to "not an answer". Let the community decide!

> 8. Where do you want to see the site and/or community go in the near future? Where don't you want to see it go? (Optional: provide the rationale behind your decisions.)

Honestly, it's hard for me to answer this question since I kind of understand the limitation of SE being a Q&A site. I think, for now, I'll just say that I want to at least *keep* the quality of the Q&A, being "more factual, and less opinion".

> 9. The community as a whole has many things that are can be seen as lack, underdeveloped, or could use further development, compared to other sites or communities (such as our sister sites within the some category). What do you see as the top three immediate things that you would like to tackle as moderator that you cannot do as a user? Why do you think these points are important and should be prioritized?

These are mostly just proposals since these still need to be coordinated with other mods. Also, all of them are related to each other:

1. Update and organize the site policy as mentioned in the [A&M Monthly Engagement Post #3](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4381/2516)
2. Update and revise [the guidance on close reason banner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339700/241919) to help each user the best. One of the most used custom reason is "identification request", and the current notice still doesn't seem effective for the poster.
3. Revise [the introduction text of the help center](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help). There's actually a customizable introduction text between the search box and "Find out more about...". While meta has a problem of discoverability and navigation (even for established users, moreover for new users), mentioning some of the FAQs on there may ease the accessibility.

> 10. How much do you know about the following series: *Naruto*, *One Piece*, *My Hero Academia*, and *Attack on Titan*? These series are some of the [top tags as of 2020](https://data.stackexchange.com/anime/query/1310219/2020-anime-manga-top-questions) that are seen more of than others. To date, there are still many (mostly poorly written) questions regarding the *Naruto* series despite it officially coming to an end in 2017. *My Hero Academia* and *Attack on Titan* appear to be getting more popular as the days go by. Knowing about these series is by no means a requirement, of course. But if candidates A and B are identical except that A has an encyclopedic knowledge of *Naruto* while B has an encyclopedic knowledge of (say) *Doraemon*, it may make a difference for voters.

I have read a few volumes of *Naruto*, not following *One Piece* and *My Hero Academia* at all, and only watched the 1st season of *Attack on Titan*.

So, while I don't really have much knowledge with the series (or, well, as my profile says "*(Googling's) Jack of all trade, (anime/manga) master of none.*"), I can still try to relate to those Q&A by reading wiki/articles and watching videos, including Japanese resources.

On the other hand, since I'm not putting serious interest in them, *I'm okay with facing spoilers* (i.e. not afraid to open the Q&A and add spoiler formatting while being "spoiled").

Comment: _I'm okay with facing spoilers_ ... respect +100